iOS React Native NFC: "The connection to service named com.apple.nfcd.service.corenfc was invalidated: - Sandbox restriction"
I already created React Native NFC feature using nfc manager package and runs smoothly on Android, but when I try to run it on iOS device I keep getting the error below:

[NFCHardwareManager areFeaturesSupported:outError:]:358 XPC Error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4099 "The connection to service named com.apple.nfcd.service.corenfc was invalidated: failed at lookup with error 159 - Sandbox restriction." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=The connection to service named com.apple.nfcd.service.corenfc was invalidated: failed at lookup with error 159 - Sandbox restriction.

The device is a iPhone 13
I already implemented the iOS setup & permission based on the NFC manager documentation but I still cannot trigger the NFC.
AddNear Field Communication Tag Reader Session Formats Entitlements to my entitlements.
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>com.apple.developer.nfc.readersession.formats</key>
    <array>
        <string>TAG</string>
        <string>NDEF</string>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>


Add NFCReaderUsageDescription, com.apple.developer.nfc.readersession.iso7816.select-identifiers to my Info.plist.
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
    <string>en</string>
    <key>CFBundleDisplayName</key>
    <string>Sales</string>
    <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
    <string>$(EXECUTABLE_NAME)</string>
    <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER)</string>
    <key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
    <string>6.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleName</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_NAME)</string>
    <key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
    <string>APPL</string>
    <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
    <string>$(MARKETING_VERSION)</string>
    <key>CFBundleSignature</key>
    <string>????</string>
    <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
    <string>$(CURRENT_PROJECT_VERSION)</string>
    <key>LSRequiresIPhoneOS</key>
    <true/>
    <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
        <false/>
        <key>NSAllowsLocalNetworking</key>
        <true/>
    </dict>
    
    <key>NSBluetoothAlwaysUsageDescription</key>
    <string>This app uses Bluetooth to connect to supported card readers.</string>
    <key>NSBluetoothPeripheralUsageDescription</key>
    <string>Connecting to supported card readers requires Bluetooth access.</string>
    <key>NSFaceIDUsageDescription</key>
    <string>Enabling Face ID allows you quick and secure access to your account.</string>
    <key>NSLocationAlwaysAndWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
    <string>O aplicativo usa sua localização para fornecer melhores serviços.</string>
    <key>NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription</key>
    <string>O aplicativo usa sua localização para fornecer melhores serviços.</string>
    <key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
    <string>O aplicativo precisa da sua localização para melhorar a experiência de uso.</string>
    <key>NFCReaderUsageDescription</key>
    <string>NFC access is required to use this feature.</string>
    <key>UIAppFonts</key>
    <array>
        <string>AntDesign.ttf</string>
        <string>Entypo.ttf</string>
        <string>EvilIcons.ttf</string>
        <string>Feather.ttf</string>
        <string>FontAwesome.ttf</string>
        <string>FontAwesome5_Brands.ttf</string>
        <string>FontAwesome5_Regular.ttf</string>
        <string>FontAwesome5_Solid.ttf</string>
        <string>FontAwesome6_Brands.ttf</string>
        <string>FontAwesome6_Regular.ttf</string>
        <string>FontAwesome6_Solid.ttf</string>
        <string>Foundation.ttf</string>
        <string>Ionicons.ttf</string>
        <string>MaterialIcons.ttf</string>
        <string>MaterialCommunityIcons.ttf</string>
        <string>SimpleLineIcons.ttf</string>
        <string>Octicons.ttf</string>
        <string>Zocial.ttf</string>
        <string>Fontisto.ttf</string>
    </array>
    <key>UIBackgroundModes</key>
    <array>
        <string>bluetooth-central</string>
    </array>
    <key>UILaunchStoryboardName</key>
    <string></string>
    <key>UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities</key>
    <array>
        <string>arm64</string>
        <string>nfc</string>
    </array>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
    </array>
    <key>UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance</key>
    <false/>
    <key>com.apple.developer.nfc.readersession.iso7816.select-identifiers</key>
    <array>
    <string>D2760000850100</string>
    <string>D2760000850101</string>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>


Does anyone know how to set it up correctly?
